# How know how many passwords i need in a wordlist?

Tags: linux, error-logging

I would like to know how many passwords I need to create a wordlist, the permutations before create the wordlist. For example if I want to create a wordlist from 1 to 9 there are 9 passwords, very easy, but if i need create a wordlist with all the permutations about aaaaa to zzzzz.

Are there any tool or script?

Comment: this is a simple logic question ... nothing to do with computers at all

Comment: If the list contains every combination, then whats the point of it?

Comment: [A generic tool to generate a wordlist is `crunch`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723520/108618).

Comment: If this is for password or hash cracking, you don't need to create a wordlist of every possible combination - that's what a brute force attack is, and all of the common tools out there already do this without needing a file, you just need to pass the character set and length. The whole point of a dictionary/wordlist attack is to avoid the slow times of brute force attacks by using a dictionary of likely passwords, because a given user's password is much more likely to be "password123" than it is to be "aabbb".

Comment: Remember that a decent password can take thousands of years to brute force if the password is not in any way likely

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad
aaaae
aaaaf
aaaag
aaaah
aaaai
aaaaj
[...]
zzzzz
```

Take care, this is a kind of *stress test* for your distro... CPU/RAM consuming...